# How to "lock" record in datagridview for multiple users

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

My company has gone from 2 people to 4 people recently and I have had to add user tracking and the like.  With that said I am now trying to tackle a way for people to see when others are in a record.  I have a datagridview that is a case selector and when someone double clicks it opens the main form for that case.  I need to be able to across users be able to show or at the very list stop them from going into that record.  I have absolutely not idea how to do this in winforms and am hoping someone could help me modify what I already have to do this.

The code being used to open the form is below:

```
    private void caseSelectorDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
        //newCityCollectionDataSet.PropertyInformationRow SelectedRow;
        newCityCollectionDataSet.CaseSelectorRow SelectedRow;

        SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)caseSelectorBindingSource.Current;
        SelectedRow = (newCityCollectionDataSet.CaseSelectorRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

        frmSummary SummaryForm = new frmSummary(this);
        SummaryForm.LoadCaseNumberKey(SelectedRow.CaseNumberKey, true, null);
        SummaryForm.LoadBRTNumberKey(SelectedRow.BRTNumber, null);
        SummaryForm.LoadWaterByAdd(SelectedRow.Num, SelectedRow.Direction, SelectedRow.Name, null);
        SummaryForm.Show();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an activity table with the userID and casenumber they're currently modifying, and then check it to see if any other user is modifying the same case.

Comment: So check to see if someone is in the case.  If not add a record to that table showing that the current user is.  When form closes delete that record?

Comment: yes, something along those lines.  when they open a case, check the table to see if anyone else has it open, if so, don't let them in, if not, add new row to table.  When they close the case, delete their row.

Comment: Thanks this is working well so far!  Only have left to delete the record when the form closes but its functioning as needed.  Thanks a ton!